# Amazon S3 - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) with Django

Tags: django, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use amazon S3 as image storage of my django website in digitalocean ubuntu 16.04.

The first error is:

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)**

After refreshing the page the error becomes into:

**Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/static/images/logo-blue.png with MIME type application/xml. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.**

This is my policy:

```
{

    "Version": "2012-10-17",

    "Statement": [

        {

            "Sid": "AddCannedAcl",

            "Effect": "Allow",

            "Principal": {

                "AWS": [

                    "arn:aws:iam::681031835429:user/username"

                ]

            },

            "Action": [

                "s3:PutObject",

                "s3:PutObjectAcl"

            ],

            "Resource": [

                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"

            ],

            "Condition": {

                "StringEquals": {

                    "s3:x-amz-acl": [

                        "public-read"

                    ]

                }

            }

        }

    ]

}
```

And this is my CORS configuration:

```
<CORSConfiguration>

<CORSRule>

   <AllowedOrigin>http://mywebsite。com</AllowedOrigin>



   <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>

   <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>

   <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>



   <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>

</CORSRule>

<CORSRule>

   <AllowedOrigin>http://www.mywebsite。com</AllowedOrigin>



   <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>

   <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>

   <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>



   <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>

</CORSRule>

<CORSRule>

   <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>

   <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>

</CORSRule>

</CORSConfiguration>
```

Any friend can help?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to use S3 for your site's static files. Is the bucket containing the files 1) public, 2) enabled for static website hosting and 3) set up with a policy that enables anyone to do an s3:getObject? It might help to describe how you set the bucket up and provide a copy of your bucket policy.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I think the issue is from the policy I will copy one.Thank you.

Comment: @redbirdo Hi friend could you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52399006/amazon-s3-with-django-cant-load-the-all-the-static-file-folders Thank you so much!