# Amazon S3 with Django can't load all the static files

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto3, django-storage

I'm using Amazon S3 to be my static and media files storage. My Django project is running in Digital ocean ubuntu 16.04.

After running `python manage.py collectstatic` I found the CSS and js did not work in my website. And then I found that the CSS and js hadn't been upload in the S3. I think this is the reason why the cs and js did not work because they are not in there.

there is only 'static' folder in S3.[image]

in this static folder there are not my project static files but the a**dmin xadmin and another plug's static files**

[image]

Above is the folder under static in S3.

When I check the url of the js it looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://myproject.s3.amazonaws.com/css/main.css?Signature=imJphDmnb4U%2BWOWHjE0Iagk2tow%3D&amp;AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAI4LFEI2ASSMOYRTQ&amp;Expires=1537337559">


<link rel="icon" href="https://myproject.s3.amazonaws.com/images/logo-blue.png?Signature=ACidpeC946mBazTtHx0McVIk6rM%3D&amp;AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAI4LFEI2ASSMOYRTQ&amp;Expires=1537337559">
```

But in my project the main.css is under **static** folder, the images are under **media** folder. This is so weird for me.

This is my project folder looks like:

[image]

And I found that, after running `python manage.py collectstatic` the system didn't copy the **static and media** at all

Here is the main part of my settings.py:

```
import os
import sys
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'apps'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'extra_apps'))


ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'myproject'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'myproject'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'myproject'
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
# the sub-directories of media and static files
STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
# a custom storage file, so we can easily put static and media in one bucket
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'myproject.custom_storages.StaticStorage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'myproject.custom_storages.MediaStorage'

# the regular Django file settings but with the custom S3 URLs
STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, STATICFILES_LOCATION)
MEDIA_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION)
```

I also created a file named custom_storages.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

class StaticStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION

class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.MEDIAFILES_LOCATION
```

I followed this tutorial https://blog.bitlabstudio.com/ultra-short-guide-to-django-and-amazon-s3-2c5aae805ce4

This issue is really very complicated to me. Any friend can help? This issue spends me 2 days to solve it.

Comment: *the system didn't copy the static and media* what it shows? where does it copy these folders?

Comment: It shows like this Copying '/home/william/kjmg/kjmgenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/i18n/km.js'  all the system copied are the static file in of the admin and some plugs.No copying of the files in my static folder and media folder.

Comment: `STATIC_ROOT` defines where to copy all static files when running `collectstatic`. just remove `STATIC_ROOT` that targets your local project.. and run it again

Comment: Hi Lemayzeur ,thank you for your reply.It is a long story how I tried to solved this issue.Up to now,I have given up Amazon S3,but using digitalocean Spaces now,there are very similar.Now I can upload all the static files in to the storage.One important thing is that I add STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
] to settings.py this is very important.But now I still have a issue:No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource And I'm trying to solve it now.Thank you man!

Comment: Can you help me with this relative question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52449377/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-wit ?Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi @Lemayzeur can you help me with this new question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52461389/loading-failed-for-the-script-with-source-https-https-nyc3-digitaloceanspa realy appreciate it!