# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource with Django digitalocean Spaces

Tags: django, nginx, digital-ocean, django-cors-headers

My Django website is hosting in digitalocean ubuntu 16.04 with Nginx.

I have setup digitalocean CORS Configurations as here https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/spaces/how-to/cors/ I added my domian name in the 'origin',checked all the options in 'Allowed Methods',the only thing I haven't done is add headers in 'Alowed Headers' because I have no idea what to add.

When I use digitalocean Spaces(a service based on and very similar as Amazon S3) as my static and media file storage.There is **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource** error:

> Access to Font at 'https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/kjmgstorage/kjmgstorage/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0' from origin 'https://kjmg.co' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://kjmg.co' is therefore not allowed access.

I tried to use django-cors-headers,but I received:

> 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)

So had to uninstalled it.

Any friend have any idea?Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you also set it up? You have to use the `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` to add the domain from digital ocean to the whitelist.

Comment: yes,I added https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com and https://kjmg.co to the CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST .After that I restart Nginx and received 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)  .So I had to uninstalled django-cors-headers .Am I right to add https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com and https://kjmg.co to the CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST?

Comment: Oh wait, sorry. I misread your question. You need to setup CORS at Digital ocean, not on your website. Check this: https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/spaces/how-to/cors/

Comment: Any update on this? I'm trying to figure out how this work too. I need to trigger a download from javascript from a url in digitalocean space. It always redirect the music in a new tabs instead of downloading. With file in the same domain, it downloads normally.

Comment: @KeitelJovin Finally I used aws storage,and it works good.

Comment: Hi @KeitelDOG did you figure out how to do it? I'm facing the exactly the same problem

Comment: Hey @Lara I don't think I could did it with Digital Ocean, I couldn't setup headers to work. But it did with ASW s3 Storage. There is nothing you can do if the server does not send the right CORS headers for you. Don't know if DO s3 still have this to fail after 2 years. Actually I'm just requesting my own Servers which in turn download songs to DO s3 and then I can send it back with cors headers to download in client side.

Comment: I had similar issues - Here's how I solved it https://stackoverflow.com/a/70315253/331655

Answer (score 3):

You need to setup CORS at Digital ocean, not on your website. Check this: [digitalocean.com/docs/spaces/how-to/cors](https://digitalocean.com/docs/spaces/how-to/cors)

Comment: Yes,I have done that,I have add my website domain in 'Origin',and checked all the options in 'Allowed Methods'.But I don't know how to fill the Allowed Headers.

Comment: You probably way over this problem, but I think I just solved it by configuring the DO spaces CORS rules with allowing all headers, using the wildcard `*` and it worked. You might want to use something more restrictive in production

Comment: Your link is broken

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty old question. But answering it cause someone may find it useful.

I have faced the same issue. First of all, if you are using DO (Digital Ocean) space you need to set the CORS header options to DO space, not in the django app.

You need to open the settings of DO space and go to `CORS Configuration`.

Then add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the Allowed header section

Then give the `Access Control Max Age` value to 600 seconds, this means the browser will cache the CORS header info for 10 mins.

Finally don't forget to clear the cache from DO spcae's edge server if you are using CDN by clicking the `purge cache` button in settings otherwise you will waste a lot of time like me.

Comment: Was running into the same problem and the `purge cache` was key, thanks for saving me many hours!

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question nonetheless I came across this issue and spent sometime to fix because DOs docs are not complete. My 2 cents is ... configure CORS as mentioned by the DOs docs (https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/spaces/how-to/configure-cors/). Once it's done... go to Spaces settings and purge the cache. This is the missing step in the docs. Configuration won't take into affect until you purge the cache.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I'm spending a lot of time with this, I have done the setup of CORS and still facing the same issue, do you have any ideas how I can solve this? Thank you

Comment: @Lara "purging cache" didn't work for you, I'm trying to see if it works now on DO s3. It worked in AWS s3 though.

Comment: @KeitelDOG I'm not using CDN

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure :

- Setting cross-origin allow everything in configure Space, for instance :

  - Origins : *
  - Allowed Methods : GET, PUT
  - Advanced Options : Header:  *
- In client need inject into header : 'x-amz-acl': 'public-read'

```html
$.ajax({
    url: data.response.pre_sign_url,
    type: 'PUT',
    headers: {
      'x-amz-acl': 'public-read'
    },
    contentType: input.files[0].type,
    cache : false,
    processData: false,
    data: input.files[0],
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response)
    },
  });
```